# What planet was Din Djarin rescued from as a child?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In the 8th (and final) episode of season 1 of *The Mandalorian*, the titular Mandalorian’s name is revealed to be [Din Djarin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Din_Djarin).

Additionally, he explains that he is not Mandalorian by birth but, rather, a “foundling”: A foundling being someone who is adopted into a tribe of Mandalorians and raised as a warrior for one reason or another.

But what planet was Din Djarin on as a child when his town — and family — were attacked by Separatist battle droids?

[image: Din Djarin on some planet being rescued by Mandalorians.]

Comment: As you know, it wasn't stated in the show (yet). Can I ask why you expect this to be answerable in any way other than waiting for & watching the second season?

Comment: Okay. FWIW, if there is any such foreign secret-telling, Wookiepedia isn't aware of it.

Comment: Also, according to wookipedia - the spiked helm the armourer wears is [from the mandalorian supercommandos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_super_commando) and resembles a [zabrak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zabrak) - inspired by darth maul. So I guess the question is when and where would the Death Watch be fighting the Confederation. Its possible that the core of the covert was Death Watch, but we don't really know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The name of the planet is not currently known, but the settlement itself does have a name.

According to *The Star Wars Book*, a canon reference written by Pablo Hidalgo among others, calls it **[Aq Vetina](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aq_Vetina)**. Not much is known about besides the fact that it was settled by humans and underwent a Separatist attack.